# CSS custom PNG cursor keeps switching

Tags: css, custom-cursor

I have this simple custom cursor code;

```
* {
    cursor: url('../../images/site-design/cursor.png'), default;
}
```

I've tested this on the latest version of Safari and Chrome on OSX. On both browsers the cursor keeps disappearing and reappearing randomly (not hovering a certain other element (just a  plain `body`). It's not flickering, it's just random disappearing and reappearing.

Any idea what might cause this? Maybe it's a specific WebKit (fork) issue?

I'm also curious why this hover approach doesn't work;

```
*:hover {
    cursor: url('../../images/site-design/cursor_pointer.png'), pointer;
}
```

Applying the code on just the `html` or `body` behaves the same.

When doing the hover on `a:hover { ...` (an a-tag) I get flickering, as the browser can't seem to figure out to show the default cursor (not even the one I gave up to act as a default everywhere, but the browser default cursor).

Comment: apply a:hover {
    cursor: url('../../images/site-design/cursor_pointer.png'), pointer;
}

Comment: I already stated that in my question, as to having the same result (`a:hover { ...`).